# Email campaigns using Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: android, iphone, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Use case: send email to users that currently don’t have the app installed. The email shall contain two links for Google (Android devices) and Apple (for iPhone). When the user taps on the link, launch Google play or Apple store app on the phone pointing to the app so that the user can download.

Is this functionality be implemented by Firebase Dynamic Links? We support Android KitKat and above. What is the minimum OS the user will need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sai, the use-case you describing is the reason why Firebase Dynamic Links exists. It does not matter how you get your link to the hands of the customers/users. You can use FDL in emails, SMS, iMessage, Facebook, Twiter etc.

You do not need to specify two links. One Firebase Dynamic Link will work on both Android and iOS. If App is not installed, the link will navigate to AppStore or PlayStore. If App is installed, the link will open the App with deep link.

If opened on desktop, the link will navigate to deep link itself. Also check out "dfl" Desktop fallback link parameter for desktop behavior.

Firebase Dynamic Links on Android supported Ice Cream Sandwich and newer. KitKat is supported by FDL.